# Showing $L: C^2[0,1] \to C[0,1],\; r(t) + q(t)\frac{d}{dt} + \frac{d^2}{dt^2}$ is bounded, with $r,q \in C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

To show this linear operator is bounded I introduce a norm on $C^2[0,1]$, namely $||y||_d := ||y||_\infty + ||y'||_\infty + ||y''||_\infty$, where $||.||_\infty$ is the sup norm over $[0,1]$.

Then to show $L$ is bounded, I can show that $||Ly||_\infty\leq M||y||_d$, for all $y\in C^2[0,1]$, and $0<M<\infty$.

I proceed using the triangle inequality

$$||Ly||_\infty=||r(t)y + q(t)y' + y''||_\infty \leq ||r(t)y||_\infty + ||q(t)y'||_\infty + ||y''||_\infty.$$

Now I want to show that the righthand side can be estimated by a positive real number $M$, **but I have trouble understanding the norm $||r(t)y||_\infty$** (and similarly $||q(t)y'||_\infty$).

I know that $||y||_\infty =\sup\{y(t):t\in [0,1]\}.$ But for $||r(t)y||_\infty$ there is already a $t$ in there. So is then $||r(t)y||_\infty = \sup\{r(t)y(s) : s\in[0,1]\} = r(t) ||y||_\infty$?

If it is this interpretation, then I think we have $$||r(t)y||_\infty + ||q(t)y'||_\infty + ||y''||_\infty \leq M_1(t) ||y||_d$$ with $M_1(t):=\max\{r(t),q(t),1\}$, **but I do not understand whether or not this has to hold for all $t$**. I have trouble understanding this since we're taking a norm of functions, not of these function's variables.

If it has to I have to take the sup norm of $r$ and $q$ in the maximum as well. So $M_2:=\max\{ ||r||_\infty, ||q||_\infty, 1\}$, and since $r,q\in C[0,1]$, they're bounded on that interval and this maximum is not infinite (and also $M_1(t)$ is not infinite for any $t$).

So then we get $||r(t)y||_\infty + ||q(t)y'||_\infty + ||y''||_\infty \leq M_1(t) ||y||_d$ for all $t$, so in particular it is $\leq M_2 ||y||_d$? And thus $L$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, 
\begin{align*}
|q(t)y'(t)|&\leq\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|q(t)y'(t)|\\
&\leq\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|q(t)|\cdot\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|y'(t)|\\
&=\|q\|_{\infty}\cdot\|y'\|_{\infty},
\end{align*}
there is no more $t$ in the end.

Comment: Thank you. Though I think this would imply that $||q(t)y'||_\infty = \sup\{ q(t)y'(t) : t\in[0,1]$ (so no $s$ as in my question)? But isn't $q(t)$ really a constant here, so that you get

||q(t)y'||_\infty = |q(t)|\cdot ||y'||_\infty (\leq ||q||_\infty \cdot ||y'||_\infty)? (same result but different steps)

But then my confusion stems from not understanding whether we have to take that sup norm on $q$, since we're taking the norm on functions, not on $t$'s, so does it have to hold for all $t\in[0,1]?

Comment: $q$ is not a constant and we are looking for $q(\cdot)y'(\cdot)$, so the result is $\|qy'\|_{\infty}\leq\|q\|_{\infty}\|y'\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: $L$ sends a function $y$ to another function, namely, $t\rightarrow r(t)+q(t)y'(t)+y''(t)$, or $r(\cdot)+q(\cdot)y'(\cdot)+y''(\cdot)$.